# lxc change default user

Tags: lxc

I'm working on LXC containers, I want to change the default user while creating the container, I was trying

```
lxc-create -t ubuntu -n ct1 -- -u user -p password
```

But this only works with "Ubuntu", if I try it with debian or fedora or "download" I get an error

```
 getopt: invalid option -- 'u'
 Template specific options can be passed to lxc-create after a '--' like this:
 lxc-create --name=NAME [-lxc-create-options] -- [-template-options]
```

I also red somewhere that I can change default user & password in **lxc-ubuntu.conf** but I want to specify different username & the password for each container I create

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu do you use?